# python setup.py install outside virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, setup.py

I have a bunch of conf file and I am running python setup.py install after initializing virtual environment. I want to install them on the machine's OS's /opt or /etc so they are available to all applications. 
How do i do this ?

Comment: Have you tried running setup.py *outside* of a virtual env yet?

Comment: The setup.py is implemented to run inside the virtualenv and thus has some configuration accordingly. Yet it install some conf which are "global" and need to be install outside virtualenv

Answer (score -1):

`setup.py` should not touch the global system-wide config.

If you need to place configuration files around the operating system files, please create a separate installation script, preferably using OS tools, and then ask the package users to run this script after completing `setup.py` installation.

E.g. on Ubuntu you would create a .deb package which takes care of operating system side of things when installing the package.